# Text gets messed up in history search(ctrl-r)

Tags: zsh

I using zsh. However, the command search history feature(ctrl-r) is giving me issues. Specifically, the text gets garbled. Everything executes correctly regardless, but UX it's a bad experience.

Using the same cloud, this issue exists in my client terminals... both in  linux system with urxvt terminal and also in wsl terminal.

How can I fix it to where the text does not get garbled? The example below shows in red circles the text that is messed up and in green what it should look like.

EDIT: here is my `PROMPT`

```
one@work ~/github/sp6-client
% echo $PROMPT
%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{green}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white}
%# %b
```

[image]

UPDATE: Options list

```
one@work ~/github/sp6-client
% setopt
alwaystoend
autocd
nobeep
correct
extendedglob
interactive
kshglob
login
monitor
printeightbit
shinstdin
zle
```

Comment: This will very likely turn out to be the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197185/ .

Comment: I am not having any issues with auto completion and I am not using printf in my prompt. I updated the og post  PROMPT.

Comment: Some old versions of `zsh` had a bug looking like that when the `HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS` option was on. What version of `zsh` are you using. Do you have `HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS` enabled? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsh/+bug/1334858

Comment: https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2013/msg00456.html, https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg00616.html fixed in https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00807.html (in 5.0.3)

Comment: No, `HIST_REDUCE_BLANKS` does not appear to be enabled. Also, this is a newer ver 5.1.1. I updated my post with the options enabled

Comment: Anyway I had missed your _Everything executes correctly regardless_ which was not the case with that issue. What's the OS? What's the output of `infocmp -x` in that `urxvt`? Is it possible that your prompt contains hidden character? `print -r -- $PS1 | LC_ALL=C sed -n l`

Comment: Can you reproduce in `env -u PS1 zsh -f`? Or with `export PS1; zsh -f`? I can't reproduce here on Linux Mint 18 with that same version of `zsh` on the `urxvt` from the `rxvt-unicode-256color` package (with `TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color`)

Comment: Is this is a problem anymore?

Comment: I stopped using Windows and use native Gentoo now