# Physical buffer in terminal is getting misaligned with display in oh-my-zsh configuration

Tags: zsh, profile, oh-my-zsh, line-editor

I have been experiencing an unusual problem in the oh-my-zsh configuration in which the cursor gets out of sync with the text. (I normally work using `screen` in `konsole`.

For instance on a new terminal line where nothing has been typed on the prompt, the cursor just shifts forward after a few seconds for no reason. It as though the starting position for the prompt gets shifted forward, like some ghost did it.

The other feature is that  it is impossible to backspace to the first cursor position and the character at that position cannot be backspaced over.

The way I see is that the visual position of the cursor and text displayed gets misaligned with its actual position within the physical buffer of the text being edited.

eg. say I enter `help` at the terminal and after that I use the up arrow key to get the previous command which should be `help`. Something seems to happen with the result that when I backspace over the `help` I can only backspace as far the `e` leaving the `h` still showing, but physically the whole word `help` in the physical buffer would have been cleared. So if I want to type `help` again the screen will display `hhelp`, but on pressing the enter key the command `help` will be executed. It wont be `hhelp`.

It only happens on the root account although I am sure that I am using identical settings for both root and end users.

The end result is that if `abcde` is showing on the screen and  backspace over `c` I more likely to have backspaced of `b`, leaving me with `acde` rather than `abde`.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

This is additional information related to the comments.

My prompt is `%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)`. It is the same on both regular accounts and `root`'s account. But the problem only occurs in the `root` account.

Comment: This is a simple variation on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197185/5132 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [autocomplete weirdness as a result of ugly hack for zsh prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197185/autocomplete-weirdness-as-a-result-of-ugly-hack-for-zsh-prompt)

Comment: My prompt is `%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)`. It is the same on both regular accounts and root's account. But the problem only occurs in the root account.

Comment: The `%{%f%b%k%}` looks correct: it contains just three visual effects escape sequences, properly encapsulated. `$(build_prompt)` calls a shell function `build_prompt` to build the rest of the prompt string; this is where the error probably is. You might run the `build_prompt` function manually (perhaps piping its output to `od -t x1z` for clarity) and compare the results when you're root vs. as a regular user. It might be some oh-my-zsh feature designed to highlight the fact that you are currently root. Finding the reason will be easier once you know the fault in the `build_prompt` output.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem in oh-my-zsh in `docker` and solved it with the following lines in the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN sed -i '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

If you're running on the host directly, try performing the actions in the `RUN` step and using `export` to export the environment variables.

To make the changes permanent, you can put the export statements in your `~/.zshrc`.

To test that this works:

```bsh
print -l -- '+--+' '|\u26A1|' '+--+'
```

Should display:

[image]