# Does zsh have some kind of diagnostic mode?

Tags: zsh, debugging, oh-my-zsh

I am experience some problem in my zsh configuration which is based on `oh-my-zsh`, which I have described at [Physical buffer in terminal is getting misaligned with display in oh-my-zsh configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559073/physical-buffer-in-terminal-is-getting-misaligned-with-display-in-oh-my-zsh-conf).

What I need to know if there is some kind of logging mode in which `zsh` can produce some information on what is happening in real-time.

The other thing is a print out of the current configuration that a more knowledgeable person can use to track the problem. By configuration I don't mean the just contents of my profile, but some more runtime state related info that can help the diagnosis.

Comment: Try `set` to print out state and `zsh -x` for trace output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.

First of all, you can `setopt xtrace` or `set -x` to get trace info on all calls in the current shell or use `zsh -x` to start a new shell with that option set. This generates *a lot* of debug info, though. Plus, it might not even include all the things you are interested in.

If you know more specifically what you are looking for, you can use `functions -t <function name>` for the specific function that you want to trace.

However, what I find to be the most reliable way to track down problems in any `.zshrc` config, is to do the following:

```bash
cd "$( mktemp -d )"
ZDOTDIR=$PWD HOME=$PWD zsh -df
```

This creates a temp folder and starts a new subshell without any config files, with its config and home dirs set to the temp folder.

Then you can execute the relevant lines in your `.zshrc` one by one by pasting them into the sub shell, until you find the point where things start to break.