# How to set shell to wrap words for long commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, prompt

I connect to a Slackware server. When a command is longer than the size of the putty window, the line continues in the same line, and the start of the command disappears as I continue adding to the same command, just putting a "<" at the beginning of the line.

[image: slackwareserver]

When I work on the Red Hat server, I can see the whole command because the console just adds lines as it needs.

[image: RedHatServer]

I don't know where I turn on word wrapping. Where can I set the Slackware server to wrap words as my Red Hat server does?
P.S.: Excuse my English.

Comment: Can you paste text as text. Images are hard to read, especially for blind people. When you do, I will up-vote.

Comment: There will be something in your `~/.bashrc` file, `~/.profile`, or one of the other configuration files, in your home directory.  I have a setting that the command is always on the 2nd line. However I would be interested, in seeing how to make it more dynamic. If you find out for your self then post the answer here.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196038/117549

Comment: If you use ksh, look at this question with no answer! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408899/configuration-of-tty-on-bsd-system) .I make a long time to understand that it come from ksh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be because you're using `bash` (or other shell which uses readline) and in your `~/.inputrc` (or global `/etc/inputrc`) you have

```
set horizontal-scroll-mode On
```

From `man readline`:

> `horizontal-scroll-mode` (`Off`)
>   When  set  to  `On`,  makes  readline  use  a  single  line for display, scrolling the input horizontally on a single screen line when it becomes longer than the screen width rather than wrapping to a new line.

Solution: delete the line (the default setting is `Off`) or explicitly set the option to `Off`:

```
set horizontal-scroll-mode Off
```

Readline uses `/etc/inputrc` only if `~/.inputrc` doesn't exist or cannot be read (`~/.inputrc` may also `$include /etc/inputrc`), so even if there's `On` in `/etc/inputrc` and you cannot or don't want to change it, you can always overwrite the setting by editing `~/.inputrc`.

The change won't automatically affect already running shells. You can reload the config with

```
bind -f ~/.inputrc
```

(see [this](https://superuser.com/q/241187/432690)), or change only that setting with

```
bind 'set horizontal-scroll-mode off'
```

---

The readline library will also fall back to `horizontal-scroll-mode` if the `TERM` environment variable is set to a terminal name not found in the terminfo database; you can check if that's the case with the `infocmp` command. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529460/308316) for how you can remediate the situation.

---

A similar interface (but displaying the `<` mark at the right end of the line) is used in some pdksh-derived shells which do not use readline (notably `mksh`, the default on Android). For that case there's no possible work-around.