# Terminal long line wrapping

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I got a small issue with line wrapping on a custom linux and I'm not sure where this is set.

When on serial console or using SSH login i get the following:

*Cursor at start of line*

```
[user@myhost ~]$ dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd>
```

*Cursor at end of line*

```
<ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

So instead of breaking into multiple lines it continues into described by the angle brackets.

Can anybody point me into the direction where I can change this behaviour? Tried messing with inputrc for readline and something like "set horizontal-scroll-mode" but I'm not sure that this is the right place

Comment: What is your shell?

Comment: Currently its sh but I have also tried bash

Comment: "When no serial console and SSH login i get the following" – so where _exactly_ do you get this behavior? "and something like «set horizontal-scroll-mode»" – what have you tried _exactly_ that you assumed based on other docs that would work but didn't?

Answer (score 4):

If your shell is `bash`, try

```
bind 'set horizontal-scroll-mode off'
```

and if that fixes it, add a `set horizontal-scroll-mode off` line to your `~/.inputrc` file.

Also, check if there's an entry in the terminfo database for the terminal from the `TERM` variable by running `infocmp`. If readline (as used by `bash`) is not able to find an entry for it, it will fall back to `horizontal-scroll-mode` (since it cannot assume that the terminal has automatic margins).

You can always export a terminfo definition from one machine to another with:

```
infocmp termname | ssh user@host tic -
```

That will create a per-user entry inside `~/.terminfo/`. If you omit `termname`, `infocmp` value will use the content of `TERM`.

---

That's also the behavior of the `mksh` (the default shell on Android) and of OpenBSD's `ksh` (with the difference that the `<` is on the right side). For that case, I don't think that it's possible to configure it away.

Comment: Changing this value worked for serial console but by SSH login the horizontal-scroll-mode doesn't seem to do anything. Instead I tried changing the TERM from xterm-256color to TERM=xterm and it changed into the correct line wrapping behavior.

Comment: Probably the terminfo definition file for xterm-256color is missing.

Comment: @LarsP yes, that probably means that bash isn't able to find the terminfo entry for `xterm-256color`, see updated answer. It's not ssh vs serial line which makes a difference.

Comment: @egmont that's certainly the case; running `TERM=blabla bash` also causes it to fall back to horiz scroll, and the differences between xterm and xterm-256color cannot account for it.

Comment: When I set this in my ~/.inputrc it would print out set horizontal-scroll-mode off on the command line every time I typed b.  I had to use 'set horizontal-scroll-mode off' without the bind or quotes instead to get this to work.