# Line wrap in xterm/bash

Tags: bash, terminal, xterm

This is my environment :

```
X server : VCXsrv Windows
Window manager : XFCE/WSL
bash : 5.0.0(1)-release
Environment variable TERM : xterm
```

When I type a command longer than the width of xterm, the line scrolls horizontally instead of wrapping the line, like

```
<lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
```

Some online articles suggest following command :

```
bind 'set horizontal-scroll-mode off'
```

but it didn't fix the issue in my context.

What else can I try to troubleshoot ?

Update 1:

```
bash-5.0$ printf "%s\n" "$PS1"
\s-\v\$
```

Update 2:

```
/bin$ tput up
tput: unknown terminfo capability 'up'
```

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/525477/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/529377/5132 .

Comment: @JdeBP, I looked at those two questions before I made the post. Apart from above `bind` command, what else can I try ?

Comment: Have you checked the `TERM` variable? If it's wrong then `off` will not work.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski As I said in post, TERM=xterm. I tried other values as well, like `xterm-256color`, or `ansi`, `vt100`, etc.

Comment: OK, we know it's `xterm`; but does your machine know what `xterm` *means*?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I ran `infocmp xterm`, and got `xterm|xterm-debian|X11 terminal emulator ...` Do I need to check anything in particular in that output ?

Comment: Probably not. Even if, I don't know what exactly. Sorry.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks anyway! My apologies for not putting the full `bind` command in the first place.

Comment: Hummm... is the "<" seen at the beginning of the line actually standing for your prompt ? If yes, could you post the output of echo $PS1 ?

Comment: @MC68020 post updated. `<` is not part of the command

Comment: When you ran `bind 'set horizontal-scroll-mode off'` did you get any message or error returned? For a `bash` shell using readline it should be the right solution, which is what's puzzling me

Comment: @roaima No messages at all following `bind` command

Comment: @Philippe "infocmp xterm ... Do I need to check anything in particular in that output ?" Yes, look for `am` (automatic right margin)

Comment: @user414777 First line does contain `am` : `am, bce, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,`

Comment: It may also be that bash is unable to get the height of the terminal and decides that your terminal has a single line. That could also cause it to horiz-scroll instead of wrap.

Comment: @Philippe have you tried putting `set horizontal-scroll-mode off` in `~/.inputrc` and starting a new shell?

Comment: @peterph I did put `set horizontal-scroll-mode off` in ~/.inputrc and starting a new shell.

Comment: @user414777 variables LINES=24, COLUMNS=80 are in line with `tput lines`, and `tput columns`

Comment: Does `setterm -linewrap on` work?

Comment: @Quasímodo After running `setterm`, still the same issue.

Comment: What you should be asking the questioner to [edit] into the question is what `tput up | hexdump` yields.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567575/5132

Comment: @JdeBP `tput up` yields `tput: unknown terminfo capability 'up'`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got `5.0.18(1)-release` source from github, compiled it which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Linux Mint, and `Bash 4.4.20` is installed by default.

I had manually compiled and installed `Bash 5.0` and ran into the OP's rendering problem.

Upgrading to `Bash 5.1` solved this rendering problem for me.