# Prompt Linux login has this < character instead of username@machine:

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, prompt

I have a problem with my Linux device.
After the boot-up sometimes the shell show me only this `<` character, I can run normal shell commands like `ls`/`cat` etc, but it shows me only 1 character. When I'm doing an `echo` I can see all the row (so only the  input has the issue of 1 character).

This is the example of my terminal after I executed the `pwd` command:

```
<d
/home/root
<
```

At the boot-up the device ran many shell scripts, so at the begging I thought was some script that didn't finish, but if a script is stack, I shouldn't be able to run normal shell command (I think). It's happening around 10% of the boot-up. If I ran `echo $PS1`:

```
<1  
\u@\h:\w\$
< 
echo $PS2 : $PS3 : $PS4   =>   > : : +
```

It seems correct.
I could access by ssh and the system looks good, I tried to kill many service/process to check if the prompt will recover, but I can recover the system  if I write '`exit`' in the prompt or I kill `/bin/login -f`  or kill `-sh` processes (it will show me the username@machine).
I tried <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> first time and it failed with

```
<logout   There are stopped jobs.
```

The second time I pressed <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> I logout and automatic login,

```
login: root (automatic login)
```

and now it's in a good state (`root@device:~#`)

Has someone any suggestion that I can try? Does someone know why there is that character? there is a way to see the last commands executed to try to understand how the device finished in that status?

I don't think is a problem of the terminal, because depends of the boot sometime work and sometime no.
I ran `printf '%s\n' "$COLUMNS"`:

```
6
```

My `TERM` environment variable:

```
TERM =   @BAUDRATE@
```

And `stty -a`:

```
speed 115200 baud;
rows 13; columns 6;
line = 0;
intr = ^C;
quit = ^\;
erase = ^?;
kill = ^U;
eof = ^D;
eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>;
swtch = <undef>;
start = ^Q;
stop = ^S;
susp = ^Z;
rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb
-parodd
cs8
hupcl
-cstopb
cread
clocal
-crtscts
-ignbrk
-brkint
-ignpar
-parmrk
-inpck
-istrip
-inlcr
-igncr
icrnl
ixon
ixoff
-iuclc
-ixany
-imaxbel
iutf8
opost
-olcuc
-ocrnl
onlcr
-onocr
-onlret
-ofill
-ofdel
nl0
cr0
tab0
bs0
vt0
ff0
isig
icanon
-iexten
echo
echoe
echok
-echonl
-noflsh
-xcase
-tostop
-echoprt
echoctl
echoke
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with the outputs of running `printf '%s\n' "$COLUMNS"`, `tput co`, and `stty -a`, and with the value of your `TERM` environment variable when this happens.  You might even be able to self-answer if you press Control+A and Control+E (or the `vi` mode equivalents) in the command-line editor and read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567575/5132 .

Comment: HI @JdeBP, i modify the question.   I have used others sw serial interface, and the problem is  the same. i don't have tput command, and ctrl+A and ctrl+E is not changing anything.

Comment: You've tagged this question `bash` and mention "bash commands", but you also mention "device". Many embedded Linux setups do not use bash (which is rather large).

Comment: @mattdm yes, you are right. it's not bash I corrected