# bash terminal display issue

Tags: bash, terminal

I have opened two terminals with different bash versions (4.2 and 5.2).

When I paste a long command, the terminal of 4.2 displays correctly, but not 5.2

```
bash-4.2$ echo kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

for 5.2

```
bash-5.2$
<kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
```

Why does this happen ? How can I troubleshoot ?

Note that both bash versions are run in terminals of Visual Studio Code.

Both terminals have TERM=xterm-256color

Comment: They both display correctly. It's just that one doesn't display in the way that you would like. See [How do I prevent sideways scrolling (and get wrapping instead) of long bash command-lines in CentOS8?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/567499/100397) as a possible duplicate